# I can't use $\int \frac{kdq}{\mathcal{r}}$ to calculate the electric potential of an infinite charge distribution, can I?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, coulombs-law

Since $\int \frac{ kdq }{\mathcal{r}}$ assumes infinity is the reference i can't use it to calculate the electric potential of an infinite charge distribution, right?

Comment: Check out https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/429992/27732